# Find the splitting field of $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Solution:Let $\mathbb E$ be the splitting field of $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb Q$.Then $x^4+1$ splits into linear factors in $\mathbb E$.
$$x^4+1=(x^2-i)(x^2+i)=(x-\sqrt i)(x+\sqrt i)(x-\sqrt {-i})(x+\sqrt {-i})$$

$$=(x-e^{i\pi/4})(x+e^{i\pi/4})(x-e^{i3\pi/4})(x+\ e^{i3\pi/4}).$$

Since $\mathbb E$ is the splitting field of $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb Q$ then $\mathbb E$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and the roots of $x^4+1$.
Thus,$$\mathbb E=\mathbb Q(e^{i3\pi/4},-e^{i3\pi/4},e^{i\pi/4},-e^{i3\pi/4}).$$

Since $e^{i3\pi/4}$ can be obtained by taking the cube of $e^{i\pi/4}$ we have $$\mathbb E=\mathbb Q(e^{i\pi/4})=\mathbb Q\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}\right).$$

Thus, $$\mathbb E=\mathbb Q\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}\right)=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-2}).$$

**Please check my solution.**

Any suggestions are heartly welcome!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Oops! $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2) \neq\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-2})$!

Comment: @NickyHekster:What's wrong in this?

Comment: $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2):\mathbb{Q}]=4$, while $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. You can multiply the elements, but that does not take away the "," ...

Comment: @NickyHekster:Thanks!! for the response.

Comment: No problem, if you deem my answer below as the right one, please tick it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be OK, excepting $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-2})$. (See the comments.)

Another, more general approach, is to look at this and noting that $x^4+1$ is the [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_8(x)$, hence $x^4+1=(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^3)(x-\zeta^5)(x-\zeta^7)$, where $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ is a *primitive* root of unity, with $\zeta^8 =1$. The splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of your polynomial is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, which is indeed $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$.