# Find the degree of the splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find the degree of the splitting field

1) $x^4 + 1$

2) $x^3 - 1$

3) $x^6 - 1$

Work:

1) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt (2i))$ is the splitting field for $x^4 + 1$ and so the degree is $4.$

2) $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$ is the splitting field for $x^3 - 1$ and so the degree is $2.$

3) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt (3i))$ is the splitting field for $x^6 - 1$ and so the degree is $4.$

Comment: Why don't you search it at this site? All answers are there. For 1), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390038/find-the-splitting-field-of-x41-over-mathbb-q), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_n$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unit.

1. The splitting field of $x^4 + 1$ is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$.
2. The splitting field of $x^3 - 1$ is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$.
3. The splitting field of $x^6 - 1$ is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_6)$.

You just need to find the degree of the [cyclotomic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ over $\mathbb Q$.